# SSTX and SSRX Overlapped

Tags: pcb-design, usb, high-speed, usb-c

I'm designing a little bridge PCB to convert USB-C to FFC Connector (iPex EVAFLEX 5-VS). I'm following the next configuration (the cable that is been replaced was USB-C to USB-A) for legacy cables, for USB 3.0 connection.

[image]

But when I was routing the traces I have realized that SSRX and SSTX pins are overlapped.

[image]

Will it be needed add 2 GND layers between top and bottom layer? I have been looking for information on the Texas Instruments High Speed Guidelines
(https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spraar7h/spraar7h.pdf?ts=1625641366070&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.de%252F ) but I haven't found nothing about overlap traces.

Comment: It looks a mess - why have you got two blue tracks exiting the via that is below and left of the R1 legend? Where is your ground plane? Have you designed track widths to ensure impedance matching?

Comment: Because there are 4 VBUS lines that should go to one, but you are right, it doesn't seem good. Yes, I'm keeping in mind control impedance. That is the question about Ground plane: use 2 internal gnd layers, using 4 layers design to avoid crosstalking or keep 2 layers design.

Comment: Just a note that the "PCB Edge" of J2 may actually need to be *off the edge* of the PCB, else connectors won't fit.  Depends on the connector of course, just make sure it will fit beforehand.

Comment: Thank you so much @rdtsc , it is a male USB, you are right, the edge should be adapted to the connector. But the most important problem is about high speed lines and crosstalking.